# 'this' inside of anonymous closure functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

```
(function(value) {
    this.value = value;
    $('.some-elements').each(function(elt){
        elt.innerHTML = this.value;        // possibly undefined (Why?)
    });
})(2);
```

Can someone explain the value of 'this' in the above code  please ?

My understanding:

`this.value = value // Line 2` - here this refers to the global object
`elt.innerHTML = this.value; // line 4` - why is this 'possibly' undefined. Please explain.

Edit: btw I have thoroughly read the explanation for 'this' in this( [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword) )  post ( from where I got the above code)

Comment: `this` has nothing to do with closures or how the function was defined - it is only affected by how the function is invoked.

Comment: I see , but I just copied the line from the linked post

Comment: Should also read the linked post/answers then - the accepted answer contains a very thorough explanation. Then it just becomes an question of "Why is the ThisBinding not as I expect it to be?" - for that, go read the documentation for the method that *invokes* the callback. In this case, that would be [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic algo that a JS interpreter uses to determine `this` is as below.

1. When a function is called via its special `call` and `apply` methods, then `this` is the first parameter to `call` or `apply`.
2. When a function is called from a bound function created via its `bind` method, then `this` is the this-value parameter to `bind`.
3. When a function is called as a method (`obj.method(params)`) then `this` is the object from which the method is fetched, `obj` in the example.
4. When a function is called otherwise, then `this` is the global object in non-strict mode or `null` otherwise.

Since `each` uses the special methods in (1) to pass the container as `this`, `this` in the inner function should be the result of `$('.some-elements')`, an array of jquery wrapped DOM nodes.

Comment: @Vlix, realized that just after I hit save.  Please see my edit.

Comment: if each() wasn't using  call/apply and instead was just calling the callback function like in `4` , then  'this' would have referred to the global object ?

Comment: @gyaani_guy, Since `each` is not defined in strict mode, yes.

Comment: There's also the `new` invocation.

Comment: @squint, Yeah.  I was limiting myself to the builtin *[[Call]]* operator, not the *[[Construct]]* operator.  *[[Construct]]* complicates `bind` since that's a source of common incompatibility with retrofitted `Function.prototype.bind` implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the function sent as callback to [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method, `this` refers to the DOM element (for each one in this collection wrapped in jQuery object), not `window`:

> More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current
>   DOM element, so the keyword `this` refers to the element.

*(BTW, that makes a bit redundant that `elt` arg; at least, it's a bit unclear why do you use both `this` and `elt` to refer to the same thing there)*.

Yet not all DOM Elements have `value` property defined: afair, it's set only for a subset of Elements: `input`, `select`, `textarea`, `option` etc. That's probably the reason why you get `undefined` as a result.

You can easily adjust this by using [**jQuery.proxy()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method:

```
$('.some-elements').each($.proxy(function(elt){
    elt.innerHTML = this.value;
}, this));
```

Now the function sent into `.each()` uses the outer `this` as its context (obviously, it no longer points to DOM Element, as `elt` does).

Comment: Re "value property ... only for input and select", `<textarea>`s and `<option>`s also have `value` properties and often `<param>`s as well.

Answer (score 1):

In line 4, `this.value` is referring to the "each" instance of `$('.some-elements')`. Inside any function, it then refers to the object that the function is operating on. In the case of the anonymous function, it's the global scope.